# select2 show checkboxes in a multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/2779/

What I'm attempting to do is make a checkbox-selectable select2 that shows how many items you have selected, instead of showing the item list. Everything works except for de-selecting an item. I think this is because I call `evt.preventDefault` in the `select2-selecting` event. Here is my code for that particular event:

```
.on('select2-selecting', function(evt) {
    var newValue = evt.object.value;
    var found = false;
    var me = this;
    var $me = $(me);
    var arr = $me.select2('data');
    arr.forEach(function(e) { 
        if(found) return;
        if(newValue === e.value) {
            found = true;
            var index = arr.indexOf(e);
            if(index === -1) console.error(e,"NOT FOUND IN ARRAY. ABORT ABORT ABORT.");
            arr.splice(index, 1);
            $me.select2('data',arr);
            changeText(me);
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

I do `evt.preventDefault()` because I want to remove the item from the select2 data list instead of adding it again (because I don't want to have it work the traditional way). Unfortunately, when I go to de-select an item it does all of the updating correctly, except for in select2 - the display list is not updated properly. I could always close and re-open the list, but I strongly prefer not to do that.

Has anyone done this successfully before? Or maybe would know where to go from here?

Comment: Really hard to understand, the only thing that does not work is that when you de-select an item it doesnt remove checkmark in list? By the way, you can replace the selector you hate with `var children = $(element).parent().find('.select2-search-choice');`

Comment: It is hard to explain as well - it doesn't remove the checkmark, yeah. I'm not sure if it's doing anything else incorrectly though.

Comment: Did you find out a solotuion?

Comment: No, unfortunately. And it looks like jsfiddle swallowed all of my progress on that problem, too. Oh well.

Comment: I've been using select2 for a while and I have to say that it's a good attempt but almost monthly I faced some kind of issue, mostly about UI design, user ergonomy and mobile friendlyness. I've suffered so much with it that now I have a completely messed custom version full of hacks. Right now I'm thinking about writing my own plugin based on jQuery and knockout.js, because I feel it will be less pain in long term. Your request sounds something like this too, I mean probably it's better to look for alternatives or create your own one.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási ultimately we did not go forward with this approach and I forgot what we actually did.

Comment: @Seiyria thank you for the feedback, actaully I was quite sure that the problem is not actual any more, I just wanted to leave the comment for future visitors :)